# Proper way to write a dynamically built PHP form with input from array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rendering, apostrophe, html-rendering

So I'm pretty new to Laravel and not at the point where I have mental bandwidth to mess with Vue.
In the meantime, I'm also trying to build forms dynamically to make the code easier on the eyes.

My code looks like this:

```
<form action='{{ route('agents.store') }}' method='POST'>
        @csrf

        @php
            $details = ['prop' => 'labelName', ...];
        @endphp

        @foreach ($details as $data => $label)
            <div class="{{ $data }}">
                <label for="{{ $data }}">
                    {{ $label }}:
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="{{ $data }}" id="{{ $data }}" value="{{ old('{{$data}}') }}">
                @error('{{ $data }}')
                    {{ $message }}
                @enderror
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

Now, this seems to work fine. I do, however, get an error when I save this and the formatting option of VSC refuses.
I assume this is because `value="{{ old('{{$data}}') }}"`

is basically doubling down on inserting a variable dynamically.

Is there a proper way I can build my form in the meantime (before learning probably Vuejs)? This form takes 15 inputs and it gets pretty messy.

Kind regards in advance.

I've tried old, trusty SO & Google. Amongst other, I found [this solid post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) but trying different apostrophes and ticks just led to variations of error message

> Parse Error : syntax error, expecting ')' on line 1 > 1 |  | ^

There are apostrophes needed for the old(''), so I've added extra and different types in the old() and the array, but I keep getting slight variations on the same error.

Comment: `value="{{ old('{{$data}}') }}"` why double `{{}}`? you are already writing php inside the first `{{}}`. Try `value="{{ old($data) }}"`

Comment: Cheers, @krisgjika I feel a bit silly now but that did the trick.
With the documentation example, I had the impression old('username') was expecting the apostrophes to make it function, so that I'd need to double down on creating a variable rather than getting rid of them.
Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the proper way to close my question, but with @krisgjika's answer I'm all set...

Comment: This should not be an answer